# How to stop logcat from Logging EVERYTHING

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Today I decided to update my Android Developer Tools. I am currently on version 22.3. Anyway, just after the update, logcat and eclipse have been behaving differently. As soon as I plug in the phone to the computer, logcat starts logging everything from the phone: EVERYTHING. SO as I browse some other apps and do stuff around it just keeps logging. So I see all the system calls and touch recognisers reports among all other stuff.

That is not much of a problem, it is annoying though, but once I start debugging my app it just keeps going on and on. Granted I use the session filter to only see logging related to my app. But eventually the full log increases till reaching those many entries as in the picture and eclipse starts to slow down everything. So as I am debugging my app, eclipse keeps getting slower and slower. Until our beloved beach ball kicks in and makes my life miserable once again. So far I have restarted eclipse like ten times today due to this behaviour.

This used to happen before, but as a bug, which restarting the phone or restarting eclipse used to stop. Today, nothing seems to be working. Is this now a feature? Is there any way for me to stop logcat from logging everything and only do it when I am debugging the app as it was before?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select specific option based your requirement

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

[image]

Comment: Yeah I am absolutely familiar with that and I use it all the time.But the problem is still there. I can set it to only assert or one very limiting option but logcat's log keep increasing regardless as it is Logging everything on the phone. Not just my app environment

Answer (score 0):

While writing the log always try to use appropriate method as per the log type for example-

```
Log.d(TAG, "Message");
Log.e(TAG, "Message");
Log.v(TAG, "Message");
Log.w(TAG, "Message");
Log.i(TAG, "Message");
```

Then you can easily filter you log. As mentioned in answer by "shylendra" it will easy to monitor.

Comment: It is not a problem with the way I am doing logging. I just plug the phone into the computer and without any action from me it starts logging like I am debugging something but I am not. In the picture you can see the session filter for my app, And from there I am getting the information I need, they way I intended it to be logging. But the all messages filter (No Filter) keeps growing as the background process for the phone (Radios, Notification Center, background apps, etc) kept logging their activity to log cat. Which is something I dont have control over and it is making eclipse crash!

Comment: it is obvious that logcat will show all the logs which are used in every application installed on phone.hundreds of applications runs on phone.

Comment: So when you plug your phone to the computer without doing anything else, logcat starts logging everything from apps to system calls from the phone until reaches million of records and eclipse crashes like shown in the picture? That doesn't seem that obvious to me.

Comment: i think you should report this issue to eclipse. i am working from a long with this IDE and never seen this kind of issue.

Comment: Well I thought it was something like a setting that I accidentally activate or something. Anyway, thanks for your input. Cheers.

Comment: if you think so then why do not download new copy of eclipse and then try.its just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In [Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?utm_source=android-studio-2022-1-1&utm_medium=studio-assistant-preview#logcat) add `package:mine` in Logcat search bar. Using this filter you will see only your local app logs and errors.

See more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#logcat-search)